# JavaFX: default button won't fire events

Tags: events, button, javafx, binding

In my code I have bound the defaultProperty of a button to some other properties like so:

```
BooleanBinding isAddResourceButtonDefault
        = resourceNameTextField.focusedProperty().or(
                resourceTypeComboBox.focusedProperty()).or(
                divisibleResourceCheckbox.focusedProperty().or(
                maxInstancesTextField.focusedProperty()).or(
                addResourceButton.focusedProperty()));
addResourceButton.defaultButtonProperty().bind(isAddResourceButtonDefault);
```

The problem is that the addResourceButton won't fire absolutely any events on pushing Enter - neither OnAction, nor OnKeyPressed.

The default property gets set just fine - I double checked (using output and ScenicView). ScenicView also doesn't show any events being fired upon hitting keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `TextField`s (and other `TextInputControl`s) process *and consume* key events that occur on them. So pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a text field will not fire an action event on the default button (because the key event never reaches the `Scene`).

If you are just trying to fire the button's action event handler when enter is pressed in one of the text fields, just add the same event handler to the text fields. E.g.

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> addResourceHandler = event -> {
    System.out.println("Add resource");
    // ...
};

addResourceButton.setOnAction(addResourceHandler);
resourceNameTextField.setOnAction(addResourceHandler);
maxInstancesTextField.setOnAction(addResourceHandler);
```

Comment: Turns out the problem does lie in a focus, but not necessarily in `TextField` one. Upon further investigation it turned out that the event magically disappears in a `TitledPane`, the button's parent, whenever it's focused. I thought panes weren't supposed to consume events? Anyway thank you for your answer, I will definitely try it out since I'm all out of other ideas.

Comment: `Pane`s don't consume events. You should probably post a [MCVE]. Also, your code explicitly makes the button the default button if and only if the text fields or combo box have focus. So if the titled pane is focused, the expected behavior would be for the button not to be fired by the enter key.

Comment: JDK bug fixed in 8u60